# PYTHON-¿Cómo podría optimizar este programa? Ya que cuando lo ejecuto mi pc se cuelga

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

qué tal? Soy nuevo por aca, estoy aprendiendo pyhton por mi cuenta con unos libros que encontre por internet, pero para este problema necesito ayuda.
Tenía que hacer un programa que dado un número (M) debo informar esa cantidad de múltiplos de 3 pero que no sean múltiplos de 5. Los primeros 5 serían [3,6,9,12,18] ya que 15 es divisible por 5.

He empezado creando una lista, luego con un 'for-in' recorro un rango del 1 al M + 1, siendo M la cantidad de multiplos que se deben informar, luego, siempre y cuando no sea multiplo de 5, multiplico por 3 a el iterador y lo guardo en la lista.

El problema llega cuando tengo que agregar un elemento más, ya que si ejecuto el codigo para 5 elementos me informa 4. Aquí está el código:

```
def multi(m):
    multi_3 = []

    for i in range(1, m + 1):
         if not (i * 3) % 5 == 0:
            multi_3.append(i * 3)

    while len(multi_3) < m:
        m += 1
        if not (m * 3) % 5 == 0:
            multi_3.append(m * 3)

    return multi_3

M = int(input("Ingrese el máximo de multiplos que quiere obtener: "))
print("Los multiplos de 3 pero no de 5 son: ", multi(M))
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! te muestra uno menos que lo que vos queres???  el for y el while en tu codigo hacen lo mismo

Comment: ahh... while len de un array al que le agregas cosas todo el tiempo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si "colgarse" es la palabra, lo que tienes es un ciclo infinito:

```
while len(multi_3) < m:
    m += 1
```

si incrementas `m` en cada iteración, aunque añadieras un item en cada una, cosa que no ocurre, la longitud de la lista siempre va a ser menor a `m`.

Necesitas otra variable que   sea la que incrementas en cada iteración y la que multiplicas por 3 para conseguir el múltiplo. Puedes usar `while len(multi_3) < m:` pero sin modificar `m` jamás, no obstante es ineficiente por la llamada a `len` en cada iteración.
Otra alternativa es usar `m` como variable de control para el ciclo exclusivamente, decrementándola cuando agregues un item a la lista solo y comprobando si ha llegado a 0:

```
def multi(m):

    multi_3 = []

    n = 0
    while m:
        if not (n * 3) % 5 == 0:
            multi_3.append(n * 3)
            m -= 1
        n += 1

    return multi_3
```

Otra versión usando una expresión de asignación (Python >= 3.8):

```
def multi(m):

    multi_3 = []

    n = 1
    while m:
        if (multiplo:= (n * 3)) % 5:
            multi_3.append(multiplo)
            m -= 1
        n += 1

    return multi_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas un ciclo que incremente la cantidad de múltiplos de 3, `mult = i *3`. Por cada iteración se pregunta si ese numero es múltiplo de 5 (`mult % 5`). Si lo fuera, entonces el `continue` retorna al `while` sin decrementar `m` ni agregar nada a la lista, de lo contrario agrega `mult` a la lista y decrementa `m`. El ciclo morirá cuando `m = 0`.

```
def multi(m):
    multi_3 = []
    i = 0
    while m > 0:
        i += 1
        mult = i * 3
        if mult % 5 == 0:
            continue
        multi_3.append(mult)
        m -= 1
    return multi_3
```